# How can I be downvoted for a question, which was closed long time ago?

Tags: support, reputation

The question was heavily criticized and closed long time ago. But recently I was downvoted for it again. Will I receive downvotes for all of my life now?

The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349924/where-is-spring-dao-in-spring-3

**UPDATE**

Every time I post question here, somebody scans my old questions and downvotes closed ones. Nobody upvoted any question. Downvoter acts on questions of different areas, so he probably judges not by sense, but by closure fact.

This is asymmetry since no equivalent option for upvote exists.

Comment: You should be able to delete it - the answer might block it but I think it needs +1 for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only times a question is immune to voting are when:

- The question is locked
- The question is deleted

So yeah, as long as your question remains around, it'll be a sitting duck for upvotes/downvotes.

You can delete your question, though, if you don't want it anymore. <strike>All it has is a zero-scoring answer which is little more than a comment anyway.</strike> The answer that was little more than a comment has been deleted already.

Comment: How one can vote for a closed question if it is not visible in the stream? Only by browsing my personal page?

Comment: Note that deleting a question makes one more likely to be question-banned.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Closed questions *are* visible. They still exist and are easy to find. Deleted questions are what aren't easy to find.

Comment: If I delete a question, will I get back all votes?

Comment: @SuzanCioc The votes will still exist, but the reputation change from all votes in closed questions will be removed.  (The votes still count towards your daily limit though, and they are still recorded in case the question is un-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the question, but perhaps you could edit it to make it more acceptable (and thus stop receiving downvotes).

OK... just looked at it.  Not sure you could make it more acceptable,  but it might be worth a shot.  (Same goes for.any of your other poorly received.questions...  editing to make them better could help).

Comment: Sorry I am not natural speaking English and didn't understand what is "it might be worth a shot"... I scanned my downvoted questions too but found nothing to delete or edit. Questions look ok for me, although some of them were newbie's.